# Ruby on Rails creates child even if parent doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I just studied ruby on rails today and I'd like some help on creating proper associations.
I have these models:

**Comment:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stammr_post
  validates :stammr_post_id, presence: true
  validates :content,  presence: true
end
```

**Post:**

```
class StammrPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments,  :dependent => :destroy
  validates :content,  presence: true
end
```

The thing is, whenever I create a Comment, and I enter a Stammr_post_id that doesn't exist, rails still accepts it as valid. Isn't that supposed to be invalid since a comment belongs to Stammr_post? The stammr_post should exist first before a comment could be made. How do I resolve this? Is it supposed to be automatic? Did I make a typo somewhere? Or do I need to do manual validation for that? Sorry, I'm kinda new to Ruby on Rails. I'm a former grails developer and I was used to the automatic associations thing. @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could validate associated `belongs_to` object (`stammr_post`) instead of database column (`stammr_post_id`).

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stammr_post
  validates :stammr_post, :content, presence: true
end
```

Comment: dude. it worked! :D thanks so much. :* I can kiss you right now. lol

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is create the Comment through the parents association. That way you are taking advantage of the association;

So instead of doing this;

```
@comment = Comment.new(:stammr_post_id => 123)
@comment.save
```

do this;

```
# Find the StammrPost first. You may want to replace params[:stammr_post_id] 
# with your StammrPost id
@stammr_post = StammrPost.find(params[:stammr_post_id]) 
@comment = @stammr_post.comments.build() 
@comment.save
```